# amazingly confusing (impossible) query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have a query which I dont know if its even possible.

I have 3 tables. one parent table and two children

[image]

The data will be presented on a grid. with
 `[account_detail]empirica_score` as the row titles
and
 `[account_detail]mfin_score` as the column titles

like this (will enplane the 99% in a sec)
[image]

So the query needs to get the `epirica_score` and `mfin_score` to determinate the placement on the grid (e.g. where the 99% is)

and get `distinct` values for `[NAEDO]startdate` where keys match.
more or less like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM paysoft_result 
WHERE result_date >= "2014-08-01" and <= "2014-09-01"
AND ( SELECT COUNT( custno ) from Paysoft_result where result = 'successful' )
AND (.. some join to get the scores from account_detail .. )
AND (.. some join to get to NAEDO..  WHERE DISTINCT(start_date))
```

I have no clue about `JOINS`

1. So you get the 2 scores to determinate the placement.
2. amount of (paysoft_result / NAEDO) * 100 = `grid value`
3. calculation need to be per customer. and the grand totals put in the grid.

I have no clue how to tackle a query like this. its for a jasper report.

any ideas?

here is some (hopefully) usefull data

**account_details table**

```
account_no    title    surname    firstname    empirica_score    mfin_score   
1000002222    "Mr"    "Petersen"    "Andrew peter"    602    97
1000002828    "Mr"    "Mars"    "Abraham"    599    97
```

**NAEDO TBALE**

```
customer_code    name                        start_date
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-08-01"
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-09-03"
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-08-01"
1000002828       "Abraham Mars"              "2014-07-03"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-05-23"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-08-22"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-07-23"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-07-23"
1000002222       "Andrew peter Petersen"     "2014-06-23"
```

**paysoft_results table**

```
custno         name                        result           result_date
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Successful"     "2014-07-05"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Tracking"       "2014-08-01"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Successful"     "2014-08-01"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Tracking"       "2014-09-03"
1000002828     "Abraham Mars"              "Successful"     "2014-09-06"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-08-25"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-06-25"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Tracking"       "2014-08-22"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-05-23"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Successful"     "2014-07-25"
1000002222     "Andrew peter Petersen"     "Tracking"       "2014-07-23"
```

Abraham has 3 payments and 3 NAEDO records (start_date DISTINCT)
that is 3 / 3 * 100 = 100%
He is represented on the grid already (although its 99%)

Andrew has 4 payments and 4 NAEDO records (start_date DISTINCT)
that is 4 / 4 * 100 = 100%
He should be in the same place on the grid.

Maybe in the background I can collect all the grid position scores and dot the percentage calculation.

representation of one customer
[image]

Comment: Could you provide sample data for the 3 tables, or setup a SQLfiddle with some data (using postgres) adding the url to the question. Images of data aren't reusable :(

Comment: So: Both accounts reside in 91-115 / 595-604. The accounts have exactly two successful paysoft_result in August. And they have three nadeo records in August. That makes 2 / 3 * 100 = 67% to show. Yes?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Thanks. I have made a edit to answer your question.

Comment: Let's see if I understand correctly: There is a grid with cells holding a percentage each. One value per cell. Abraham and Andrew belong in the same cell. So it's 7 / 7 * 100 = 100%. Yes?

Comment: Yes. other customers have less payments than NAEDO records so it wount always be 100% like here. but yes you have got it perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should be about the query needed. I select the accounts and their grouping strings (row and col group) from account_detail. I count successful paysoft results per account and distinct naedo start dates per account. Then I join and aggregate. It's up to Jasper Reports then to pivot and show data in a grid.

```
select 
  ad.escore,
  ad.mscore,
  sum(ps.cnt) / sum(n.cnt) * 100 as percent
from 
(
  select 
    account_no,
    -- 602 becomes '595-604'
    to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 5, , '9999') || '-' || to_char(trunc(empirica_score - 5, -1) + 14, '9999') as escore,
    -- 97 becomes '76-100'. Change the expression to group differently.
    to_char(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 1) || '-' || to_char(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 25) as mscore
  from account_detail
) ad
join 
(
  select custno, count(*) as cnt
  from paysoft_result 
  where result = 'Successful'
  group by custno
) ps on ps.custno = ad.account_no
join 
(
  select customer_code, count(distinct start_date) as cnt
  from naedo 
  group by customer_code
) n on n.customer_code =  = ad.account_no
group by ad.escore, ad.mscore;
```

Comment: Thorsten. wow man you are really awesome you know. Thanks SO much.  I got one error in the query `ERROR:  function to_char(integer) does not exist
LINE 12:     to_char(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 1) || '-' || to_c...`

Comment: I used `cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 1 as text) || '-' || cast(((mfin_score - 1) / 25) * 25 + 25 as text) as mscore`  
and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I can give this request for showing the results that you need

if there any error tell me to correct it

for jasper its easy if the request work correctly

good luck

```
SELECT paysoft_results.COUNT(custno),
  account_details.impirica_score,
  account_details.mfin_score ,
  naedo.start_date
FROM account_details
INNER JOIN paysoft_results pr
ON (account_details.account_no = paysoft_results.custno)
INNER JOIN naedo
ON (account_details.account_no =naedo.customer_code)
WHERE pr.result_date BETWEEN '2014/08/01' AND '2014/09/01'
AND paysoft_results.result = 'successful'
```

Comment: Wow. thats amazing understanding. I did get this error though  
`ERROR: schema "pr" does not exist` Dont understand why. The edit is also to just correct some table names.

Comment: Table and field names are correct as per you answer(edit), but it keeps complaining about `ERROR:  schema "pr" does not exist`
Could it be that `postgres` dont use `INNER JOIN`s?

Comment: pr.COUNT(custno)? So The table pr has a member function COUNT? I don't think so, and moreover I think this is what the dbms is complaining about.

Comment: i think ppostgres dont accept variables so i edit my answaer try it

Comment: But still: Does the paysoft_results table have a COUNT function? Does postgres even support such? I think you want to do something entirely else. Aggregate? But there is no GROUP BY clause in your query...